# Use Ant for post-processing code optimization

Tags: eclipse, optimization, ant, post-processing

Is it possible in Eclipse to use Ant for post-processing in order to optimize Php/Html/Css/Javascript code?

All sorts of user code can be optimized (comment removal, minification, optimization, image minification etc)

My plan is to make an environment where programmers sort-of compile(optimize) the code before sending it to web server (apache lets say).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Right-click on your project, select "Properties...", then go to the *Builders* configuration panel, add a new Ant builder, and select which targets must be run at which moment.